Return the index of a date match
I'm drawing a blank even though it seems straightforward.
I have a list of dates in an index:
book_df.index
Out[44]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2023-08-13 15:10:47.284558', '2023-08-13 15:10:48.005322',
               '2023-08-13 15:10:48.005953', '2023-08-13 15:10:49.022438',
               '2023-08-13 15:10:53.218365', '2023-08-13 15:10:54.246143',
               '2023-08-13 15:10:54.246874', '2023-08-13 15:10:54.247330',
               '2023-08-13 15:10:55.270271', '2023-08-13 15:10:55.270948',
               ...
               '2023-08-14 14:00:00.208915', '2023-08-14 14:00:00.209017',
               '2023-08-14 14:00:00.209119', '2023-08-14 14:00:00.209221',
               '2023-08-14 14:00:00.209323', '2023-08-14 14:00:00.209425',
               '2023-08-14 14:00:00.209527', '2023-08-14 14:00:00.209629',
               '2023-08-14 14:00:00.209730', '2023-08-14 14:00:00.209832'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=1230021, freq=None)

How do I return the index value for a matching date?  This returns a boolean mask, but would like to return index value of 0.
book_df.index == rng[0]
Out[60]: array([ True, False, False, ..., False, False, False])


Can you please write a [mre]? Emphasis on both minimal and reproducible; they're both important. We need book_df and something to match it against.

numpy.where will return the list of indexes that are True, but what's the point?  You already have the index value(s), because you used them to search.  The date IS the index, not the row number.  You can use the index values to index more easily than the row numbers.

@TimRoberts, I have a second dataframe without index that I'd like to filter...but you're 100% right, already have the mask, don't need the location, per se (hence the blanking)

Ensure that rng[0] is a datetime object: Make sure rng[0] is a datetime object or a string that can be converted to a datetime object. Use .get_loc() to find the index position:
import pandas as pd
search_date = rng[0]
index_position = book_df.index.get_loc(search_date)
print(index_position)

# If search_date is not found in the index, get_loc() will raise a KeyError. You might want to handle this case by using a try-except block:

try:
    index_position = book_df.index.get_loc(search_date)
    print(index_position)
except KeyError:
    print("Date not found in the index.")


You shouldn't post answers that are strictly code.  Always add an explanation saying what you did and why it works.

I am not posting the whole code this is sample piece of code
Explanation:  Ensure that rng[0] is a datetime object: Make sure rng[0] is a datetime object or a string that can be converted to a datetime object.
Use .get_loc() to find the index position:

No, modify your answer to include the explanation.  Don't put it in comments.  The answer should be complete.

you are actually really close to the solution, you just need to pass the mask as a condition to filter the index, solution below:
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2023-08-13 15:10:47.284558', '2023-08-13 15:10:48.005322',
               '2023-08-13 15:10:48.005953', '2023-08-13 15:10:49.022438',
               '2023-08-13 15:10:53.218365', '2023-08-13 15:10:54.246143'])
rng = ['2023-08-13 15:10:47.284558', '2023-08-13 15:10:48.005322',
               '2023-08-13 15:10:48.005953', '2023-08-13 15:10:49.022438',
               '2023-08-13 15:10:53.218365', '2023-08-13 15:10:54.246143']
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5,6]}, index=x)

df.index== rng[0] ### you are here, (this statement is returning you a boolean mask), just filter the index using this mask as shown below
 
print(df.index[df.index== rng[0]][0])  ####output --> Timestamp('2023-08-13 15:10:47.284558')

